# Speeding up Python iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to seek through a List of roughly 1.300.000 Lines.
The chronological order is important!

It has a shape like this:

```
Z    X      Y
18,139869,87718
18,139869,87719
18,139869,87722
18,139869,87725
18,139869,87726
18,139869,87751
18,139869,87752
18,139869,87841
18,139869,87842
18,139869,87843
18,139869,87844
18,139869,87845
18,139869,87846
18,139869,87847
18,139869,87861
18,139869,87862
18,139869,87882
18,139869,87886
18,139869,87887
18,139869,87888
18,139869,87889
18,139869,87890
18,139869,87891
18,139869,87902
18,139869,87912
18,139869,87913
18,139869,87914
18,139869,87918
18,139869,87919
18,139869,87933
18,139869,87934
18,139869,87936
18,139869,87938
```

of this list I'm creating another list:

```
18,139869,87718
18,139869,87719
18,139869,87722
18,139869,87723
18,139869,87725
18,139869,87727
18,139869,87751
18,139869,87753
18,139869,87841
18,139869,87848
```

and so on...

im using this Python Code inside a Class Method:

```
while idx in range(len(self.zoom_list)):
        this_Xelement = self.zoom_list[idx]
        next_Xelement = self.zoom_list[(idx + 1) % len(self.zoom_list)]
        #get diffenrences in line ntries for x and y coordinate
        X = int(next_Xelement[1]) - int(this_Xelement[1])
        y = int(next_Xelement[2]) - int(this_Xelement[2])
        #set start coordinate for Bounding Box
        x_start = int(this_Xelement[1])
        y_start = int(this_Xelement[2])
        #decide witch coordinate to set as end coordinet for rendering Bounding Box
        if X == 0:
            if y > 1:
                x_end = int(this_Xelement[1]) + 1
                y_end = int(this_Xelement[2]) + 1
            elif y == 1:
                bidx = idx
                for bidx, row in enumerate(self.zoom_list, bidx):
                    this_Yelement = self.zoom_list[bidx % len(self.zoom_list)]
                    next_Yelement = self.zoom_list[(bidx + 1) % len(self.zoom_list)]
                    y2 = int(next_Yelement[2]) - int(this_Yelement[2])
                    if y2 == 1:
                        continue
                    elif y2 > 1:
                        x_end = int(this_Xelement[1]) + 1
                        y_end = int(this_Yelement[2]) + 1
                        break
                    elif  y2 < 1 and bidx == (len(self.zoom_list) - 1):
                        x_end = int(this_Xelement[1]) + 1
                        y_end = int(this_Yelement[2]) + 1
                        break
                idx = bidx

        elif  X == 1:
            x_end = int(next_Xelement[1]) + 1
            y_end = int(this_Xelement[2]) + 1
        else:
            x_end = int(this_Xelement[1]) + 1
            y_end = int(this_Xelement[2]) + 1

        #create BB coordinates from extracted start and end tile coordinates
        r_Up = self.num2deg(int(x_start), int(y_start), self.zoom)
        l_Down = self.num2deg(int(x_end) - 0.25, int(y_end) - 0.25, self.zoom)

        #create bounding box for rendering with mapnik (left down + right up)
        bb = l_Down + r_Up
        self.bb_list.append(bb)
        idx += 1
```

is there a way to speed it up? 2:48h are too long.

Comment: This might be more suitable to [codereview.se], but read their guidelines before posting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) in python 2.x creates a list. The expression in while predicate causes creation/destruction of the list every iteration; creating 1,300,000 items list 1,300,000 times as a result.

```
while idx in range(len(self.zoom_list)):  # this is run every iteration
    ...
    idx += 1
```

By using `for` statement with `xrange`, it will be easier to read, no list creation/destruction occurs.

```
for idx in xrange(len(self.zoom_list)):
    ...
```

---

Another minor issue: There's unnecessary, repeated `int` calls.

Remove unnecessary `int` calls. For example `int(y_start)`, `int(y_end)` can be replaced with `y_start`, `y_end` before `y_start`, `y_end` are already `int` objects.

Also, if possible, convert `self.zoom_lsit` to contains `int`s beforehand to avoid repeated `int` calls.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that `idx` is modified inside the `while` loop. But still, the first mention about `range` is valid; avoid repeated `range` calls:

```
while 0 <= idx < len(self.zoom_list):
    ...
    idx += 1
```

Comment: nice it works ! decreased from 3 hours to 42 seconds!!